# Doubly periodic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following translations: $T_{\lambda_1}: x+ \lambda_1$ and $T_{\lambda_{2}}: x+ \lambda_2$ acting on the complex plane. More specifically, let us look at $T: x \to x+a \lambda_1 + b \lambda_2$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers. I think the doubly periodic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ would be those such that $f(Tx) = f(x+a \lambda_1 + b \lambda_2) = f(x)$ for all $a,b, \lambda_1, \lambda_2$. How would you find all of the doubly periodic functions on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Holomorphic? Meromorphic? Or just functions in general?

Comment: functions in general

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* mean functions in general, let $E$ be the (half-open) quadrilateral with vertices at $0$, $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_1 +\lambda_2$. (For this to really make sense, you want $\lambda_1/\lambda_2 \notin \mathbb{R}$.)

Then **every** function defined on $E$ can be (uniquely) extended to a doubly-periodic function in a fairly obvious way.